# Captcha Alternative for China

Tags: feature-request, captcha

I'm getting a "Human Verification" request. That seems reasonable. However, the only method is to solve a captcha from a server blocked by the PRC. Since the captcha won't load, I can't post anything.

I'm requesting a fallback alternative captcha service if the Google one fails to load.

Comment: Possible work around: The check that sometimes triggers the captcha doesn't seem too tough to bypass. I mostly hear people getting it when trying to post an answer in a very short period of time, in particular when they type it all out then past it into the editor.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Thanks for that, I'll keep it in mind for next time. It won't let me post since it's already asked me. I could clear my cookies/cache but logging in is its own fiasco without a working VPN.

Comment: Depending on what causes the captcha, you might be able to avoid triggering it. For example, I always get one when I post something I've been sitting on for a few days.